# Possible extrapolation of old German word "hansa" to protogermanic and possibly common root with Sanskrit "sangha"

Tags: germanic-languages, sanskrit, proto-germanic

I came across a discussion about if "Lufthansa" means air-Swan, inspired by the sanskrit word *hansa* swan. Which is of course wrong as it has its origins in the old german word *hansa* for group or fellowship. But inspired by the question I thought about which would be the sanskrit "version" of the word (in the sense of which one might have come from the same origin, I miss the term sry). My idea was *sangha*, it means also group and the like and it would also match the s/k,h phonetic change as suggested by satem-kentum. My questions are

1. How far can we extrapolate the old german word *hansa* back to pre-germanic languages how would it have sounded there?
2. Could it be that *hansa* and *sangha* have a common origin?
3. Where comes Sanskrit *sangha* from?

(I am no expert for linguistics, so please apologize eventually wrong terms or conceptions, I am happy to learn about how to do it better)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sangha is from Sanskrit *saṃ- (PIE *[sem](https://lrc.la.utexas.edu/lex/master/1686)) "together" + *[han](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BF)- (PIE *[gʷʰén](https://lrc.la.utexas.edu/lex/master/0753)) "strike, kill", and originally in Sanskrit meant "struck, put together". Hansa (referring to the Hanseatic league) is reconstructed to Proto-Germanic *[hansō](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/hans%C5%8D), and deeper relations are speculative. Germanic **h* would derive from either PIE **k* or **k'*; PIE **k* becomes Skt. [k] and PIE **k'* appears as [ś] in Skt (**š* in the Iranian branch). If a Sanskrit word with [ś] were actually related to a Germanic word with **h* (**x*), we would have to conclude that at least one of the words was a borrowing from another language. For example, *path* is clearly derived from IE **pent*, but the consonant phonology is wrong for native Germanic development, and it is hypothesized that the Germanic word comes through Iranian.
Despite the meaning similarities, the historical sound differences indicate that the words are unrelated.

Comment: You need to put * before reconstructed forms.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer (I am quite impressed)! But do I understand correctly that some relation, at last to the "saṃ" part, given it was Indo-Iranian š/ś, we at least cannot completely rule out, or are they also too different?

Comment: @user6726 btw do you mean "saṃ- = han-, sem", since afaik saṃ- has that meaning (put togehter). Or would sangha be really composed out of three bits: saṃ+(han-/sem)+gʷʰén?

Comment: Hopefully I've clarified the meaning parts of the Sanskrit form.

Comment: Is **IE** pent a typo? "is clearly derives"? And we need the asterisks before all the reconstructed forms.

Comment: With all due respect, what do you mean by a reconstructed IE form? In historical linguistics, it's always PIE.

Comment: @fdb I'm not quite sure why the mentioned Sanskrit stems are marked as reconstructed though. Aren't they real stems? Could you please clarify?

Comment: @AlexB. The answer has been (wrongly) edited since I commented on it. The Skt lemmas should not have an asterisk; the PIE forms should.

Comment: Current Sanskritist usage is to transcribe verbal roots in caps (HAN).

Comment: @user6726 " If a Sanskrit word with [ś] were actually related to a Germanic word with *h (*x), we would have to conclude that at least one of the words was a borrowing from another language." What about the famous satem/kentum/hundert? Would't that be an example? Or is it really the [ś] versus [s] which makes here the difference?

Comment: "Or is it really the [ś] versus [s] which makes here the difference? " Yes.